# Importing BeautifulSoup to Monkeyrunner

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, monkeyrunner

Is there a way to import BeautifulSoup (or something similar for web scraping) to monkeyrunner?

Importing BeautifulSoup to Python program was successful. However, I was getting the importError when importing to monkeyrunner

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

After some digging, I appended the BeautifulSoup path name

> import sys
>
> sys.path.append("path/to/monkeyrunner/directory/the_filename.egg")
>   sys.path.append("path/to/monekeyrunner/directory")

This enabled Monkeyrunner to correctly see the directory for BeautifulSoup. However, complains about something in BeautifulSoup; see below:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input '' ''", ('C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-
packages\\bs4\\__init__.py', 186, 56, "                if ((isinstance(markup, b
ytes) and not b' ' in markup)\n"))
```

Again, there is no error with importing to python. Any suggestion as to why this might be the case with monkeyrunner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is 100% python. It will provide you with almost all the functionality in `monkeyrunner` and more.

`bs4` can be imported in your script with no problems.

Comment: This was not what I expected as I wanted a way to work with the monkeyrunner. But this turns out to be better option, because, I am no longer limited to only use the modules available in monkeyrunner. 
For the benefit of anyone else encounter similar issue, I would like to point out, I was able to use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) as a replacement for monkeyrunner  with the help of [adbclient](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/03/adbclient-under-hood-of.html).

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solved your problem. There are also other AndroidViewClient/culebra features not available in monkeyrunner like multi-device testing, automatic test generation, GUI, etc.